# error when refresh page with angular 4 project on Nginx

Tags: angular, nginx

I'm trying to push my angular 4 build project to production.
when I refresh  page  I have  this error:

" 404 Not Found "

here is my nginx setting:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  # server_name 91.134.234.212;
  server_name localhost;
  root  /home/www/dropnet;
  error_page 404 /404.html;
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;

  location / {
    #try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ $uri/ /index.html = 404;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  index index.html index.htm;
  # Here we proxy pass only the base path
  location /api {
    proxy_pass http://api_dropnet.neobe.com/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For 
    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

  # Here we proxy pass all the browsersync stuff including
  # all the websocket traffic
  location /browser-sync {
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass         /home/www/dropnet;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
  }
}
```

please what I'am doing wrong?

below is files on webserver

[index.html and app files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYpkv.png)

Comment: since you still have the error, please post the whole nginx config and the nginx error logs

Comment: I just update my post nginx configuration file

Comment: just saw that you have a typo in `sername localhost;` - should be `server_name localhost;` otherwise it looks good now

Comment: I updated my and changed sername to server_name but always the same error " error 404 not found"

Comment: ok you have to provide more information. What url do you request? When does the error happen? Because you write `when I refresh...`? And please post the whole nginx.conf, not only the server block

Comment: ok the entry point of my app is http://dropnet.dropcloud.fr/ which is home   page  , once get to home page everything work fine  but if I reload page with  " F5" , error happend at this time. what I posted is  whole of nginx.conf

Comment: ok, there has to be more, this is not a complete nginx config! Try looking at `etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and `etc/nginx/conf.d/*`. Additionally there has to be another because trying to access dropnet.dropcloud.fr works, although you have the server_name localhost in your post. So the config in your post is not even used! Maybe also have a look at https://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html and you'll see that `http{}` must be always the top block around server